# Autocovariance of harmonic oscillator in fluid (Langevin Equation)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am looking to work out an analytical solution (if it is known) for the autocovariance $Cov[X_s,X_t]$ of a particle which behaves according to the Langevin equation for a [Harmonic Oscillator in a fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation#Harmonic_oscillator_in_a_fluid), or:

$mdV_t = -\lambda V_tdt -kX_tdt+dW_t$
$dX_t = V_tdt$

Where $\lambda$ $k$ $m$ are constants. Assume $X_0=0$ $V_0=0$.

According to the wiki, the particle's position/velocity converge to the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution), but I don't know how I can get from that to $Cov[X_s,X_t]$